# Storing large SQL datasets with variable numbers of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In America’s Cup yachting, we generate large datasets where at every time-stamp (e.g. 100Hz) we need to store maybe 100-1000 channels of sensor data (e.g. speed, loads, pressures). We store this in MS SQL Server and need to be able to retrieve subsets of channels of the data for analysis, and perform queries such as the maximum pressure on a particular sensor in a test, or over an entire season.

The set of channels to be stored stays the same for several thousand time-stamps, but day-to-day will change as new sensors are added, renamed, etc... and depending on testing, racing or simulating, the number of channels can vary greatly.

The textbook way to structure the SQL tables would probably be:

OPTION 1

```
ChannelNames
+-----------+-------------+
| ChannelID | ChannelName |
+-----------+-------------+
| 50        | Pressure    |
| 51        | Speed       |
| ...       | ...         |
+-----------+-------------+

Sessions
+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+
| SessionID |   Location    | Boat  | Helmsman |
+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+
| 789       | San Francisco | BoatA |  SailorA |
| 790       | San Francisco | BoatB |  SailorB |
| ...       | ...           | ...   |          |
+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+

SessionTimestamps
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+
| SessionID   | TimestampID | DateTime               |
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+
| 789         |       12345 | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:00 |
| 789         |       12346 | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:01 |
| ...         |       ...   | ...                    |
+-------------+-------------+------------------------+

ChannelData
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| TimestampID | ChannelID | DataValue |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 12345       | 50        | 1015.23   |
| 12345       | 51        | 12.23     |
| ...         | ...       | ...       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

This structure is neat but inefficient. Each DataValue requires three storage fields, and at each time-stamp we need to INSERT 100-1000 rows.

If we always had the same channels, it would be more sensible to use one row per time-stamp and structure like this:

OPTION 2

```
+-----------+------------------------+----------+-------+----------+--------+-----+
| SessionID | DateTime               | Pressure | Speed | LoadPt   | LoadSb | ... |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+-------+----------+--------+-----+
| 789       | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:00 | 1015.23  | 12.23 | 101.12   | 98.23  | ... |
| 789       | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:01 | 1012.51  | 12.44 | 100.33   | 96.82  | ... |
| ...       | ...                    | ...      |       |          |        |     |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+-------+----------+--------+-----+
```

However, the channels change every day, and over the months the number of columns would grow and grow, with most cells ending up empty. We could create a new table for every new Session, but it doesn’t feel right to be using a table name as a variable, and would ultimately result in tens of thousands of tables – also, it becomes very difficult to query over a season, with data stored in multiple tables.

Another option would be:

OPTION 3

```
+-----------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| SessionID | DateTime               | Channel1 | Channel2 | Channel3 | Channel4 | ... |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| 789       | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:00 | 1015.23  |    12.23 | 101.12   | 98.23    | ... |
| 789       | 2013/08/17 10:30:00:01 | 1012.51  |    12.44 | 100.33   | 96.82    | ... |
| ...       | ...                    | ...      |          |          |          |     |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

with a look-up from Channel column IDs to channel names – but this requires an EXEC or eval to execute a pre-constructed query to obtain the channel we want – because SQL isn’t designed to have column names as variables. On the plus side, we can re-use columns when channels change, but there will still be many empty cells because the table has to be as wide as the largest number of channels we ever encounter. Using a SPARSE table may help here, but I am uncomfortable with the EXEC/eval issue above.

What is the right solution to this problem, that achieves efficiency of storage, inserts and queries?

Comment: What about the first solution seems inefficient?

Comment: @HartCO If we have 1000 channels, then every time-stamp requires 1000 row inserts, instead of a single row insert for Options 2 or 3 - which in our experience is significantly slower. Also in terms of storage, every time-stamp needs 1000 rows * 3 columns, instead of 1 row * 1002 columns, so nearly 3 times as many values in total.

Comment: there is another option: use an XMLType column. Not that I am suggesting it, but it is still an option

Comment: If your fields will change, but, the old data will not affected bby new fields, it looks like a good case to use NoSQL databases. Fo example MongoDb, and store your data as "document" entity.

Comment: If you need SQL only, so you must use 1st option. You can make more de/normalizing tables depend of you final goal. Are you you looking for fast inserts? Fast reads? What is the ratio of read/write operations? For reads use indexes, for inserts disable/remove indexes. HDD space is low cost today, so maybe you need to worry about ram or speed...  not about size of the data on hdd. Hard to suggest right way to do without knowing how you define efficiency....

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich Exactly what I was intending to get to, well put.  It all depends on priorities, but the first solution probably the "textbook" sql option for good reason.

Comment: I'd agree with @AlexanderRavikovich here. Is there a _specific_ issue that you are trying to combat, or are these hypothetical limitations you envisage hampering the project? Each approach will have pros and cons, but I suspect you'll find performance adequate. Can you maybe cache a certain time period of sensor data (say a minute or two) and then handle it as one set based operation rather than loads and loads of individual row by row inserts? Maybe that would be a way of addressing any slowness with Insert issues.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @Alexander, ratio of read/write operations is probably in the order 1:1 on average; data is written once, some common channels are read several times, some are never read again - depending on what we're interested in after sailing. Fast write time is important because during sailing we log to a local database, then have to transfer the day's sailing data to the master on-shore database ASAP for people to access it; fast reads are important so users aren't waiting for a long time when requesting a channel (typically all samples of one channel for an entire session).

Comment: We have previously found Option 1 too slow to write, so have been using a messy mix of 2 and 3, but with the view here that Option 1 is the right way to go, we will look at it again and benchmark specific use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Option 1.

Data integrity is first, optimization (if needed) - second.

Other options would eventually have a lot of `NULL` values and other problems stemming from not being normalized. Managing the data and making efficient queries would be difficult.

Besides, there is a [limit on the number of columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms143432.aspx) that a table can have - 1024, so if you have 1000 sensors/channels you are already dangerously close to the limit. Even if you make your table a [wide table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986(v=sql.105).aspx), which allows 30,000 columns, still there is a limitation on the size of the row in a table - 8,060 bytes per row. And there are certain [performance considerations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645884(v=sql.105).aspx).

I would not use wide tables in this case, even if I was sure that the data for each row would never exceed 8060 bytes and growing number of channels would never exceed 30,000.

I don't see a problem with inserting 100 - 1000 rows in Option 1 vs 1 row in other options. To do such `INSERT` efficiently don't make 1000 individual `INSERT` statements, do it in bulk. In various places in my system I use the following two approaches:

1) Build one long `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO ChannelData (TimestampID, ChannelID, DataValue) VALUES
(12345, 50, 1015.23),
(12345, 51, 12.23),
...
(), (), (), (), ........... ();
```

that contains 1000 rows and execute it as normal `INSERT` in one transaction, rather than 1000 transactions (check the [syntax details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)).

2) Have a stored procedure that accepts a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). Call such procedure passing 1000 rows as a table.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ChannelDataTableType] AS TABLE(
    [TimestampID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChannelID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DataValue] [float] NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertChannelData]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ParamRows dbo.ChannelDataTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChannelData]
            ([TimestampID],
            [ChannelID],
            [DataValue])
        SELECT
            TT.[TimestampID]
            ,TT.[ChannelID]
            ,TT.[DataValue]
        FROM
            @ParamRows AS TT
        ;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
GO
```

If possible, accumulate data from several timestamps before inserting to make the batches larger. You should try with your system and find the optimal size of the batch. I have batches around 10K rows using the stored procedure.

If you have your data coming from sensors 100 times a second, then I would at first dump the incoming raw data in some very simple CSV file(s) and have a parallel background process that would insert it into the database in chunks. In other words, have some buffer for incoming data, so that if the server can't cope with the incoming volume, you would not loose your data.

Based on your comments, when you said that some channels are likely to be more interesting and queried several times, while others are less interesting, here is one optimization that I would consider. In addition to having one table `ChannelData` for all channels have another table `InterestingChannelData`. `ChannelData` would have the whole set of data, just in case. `InterestingChannelData` would have a subset only for the most interesting channels. It should be much smaller and it should take less time to query it. In any case, this is an optimization (denormalization/data duplication) built on top of properly normalized structure.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer and great suggestions. I'd delayed replying because we're running benchmarks, and I'd hoped to have results by now... but we're still working on it! I will reply in more detail when I have some timing data.

Answer (score 1):

Is your process like this:

1. Generate data during the day
2. Analyse data afterwards

If these are separate activities then you might want to consider using different 'insert' and 'select' schemas. You could create a schema that's fast for inserting on the boat, then afterwards you batch upload this data into an analysis optimised schema. This requires a transformation step (where for example you map generic column names into useful column names)

This is along the lines of data warehousing and data marts. In this kind of design, you batch load and optimise the schema for reporting. Does your current daily upload have much of a window?